# Using FOR in batch programing

Tags: batch-file

I encounter a problem when using FOR in a batch script.

**My batch file contain bellow :**

```
Echo off
set max_page=2
for /l %%i IN (1,1,%max_page%) do (
echo.
echo  Page %%i off %max_page%
echo  ========================================================
echo page %%i

:find_server
set "result=true"
echo page %%i
wget -S --spider -t 1 http://portal/ 2> check_portal.txt
echo page %%i
for /f "skip=1 tokens=4" %%b in ('findstr /L "Connecting" check_portal.txt') do set status=%%b
echo page %%i
if "%status%"=="failed:" set result=false
echo page %%i
if "%result%"=="false" (
    goto :find_server
)else goto :server_connected

:server_connected
for /f "skip=3 tokens=2 delims=/" %%c in ('findstr /L "Location: " check_portal.txt') do set server_portal_upd=%%c
echo page %%i
)
pause
```

**Result :**

```
 Page 1 off 2
 ========================================================
page 1
page 1
page 1
page 1
page 1
page %i
Press any key to continue . . .
```

But if the line below is removed , the script runs successfully

```
:find_server
    set "result=true"
    echo page %%i
    wget -S --spider -t 1 http://portal/ 2> check_portal.txt
    echo page %%i
    for /f "skip=1 tokens=4" %%b in ('findstr /L "Connecting" check_portal.txt') do set status=%%b
    echo page %%i
    if "%status%"=="failed:" set result=false
    echo page %%i
    if "%result%"=="false" (
        goto :find_server
    )else goto :server_connected

    :server_connected
    for /f "skip=3 tokens=2 delims=/" %%c in ('findstr /L "Location: " check_portal.txt') do set server_portal_upd=%%c
```

Why `Line 8` to appear `page %i` not `page 1`?
where is the mistake? Correct me please.
Thank you very much for your sugesstion

Answer (score 2):

Labels `:find_server` etc. terminate the `for` loop. Try restructuring to use `call :subroutineneame`

BTW - there must be a space on **both** sides of the `else` keyword.